# Python: better logic way to resolve "Atom learning"

Tags: python, logic

I'd like to improve my code in Python. I'm looking for a logic help here to get this same result with less code.

My procedure gets a string of atoms through parameter and "learn" them, returning the list of atoms that it has learned.

I would like to know if there's any way to optimize my code.

```
def mol_term(molecule):
    upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    list_of_atoms = []

    for i in range(len(molecule) - 1): #goes all string long
        if molecule[i] in upper: 
            if not molecule[i+1] in upper:
                temp = molecule[i] + molecule[i+1]  #if atom has two letters
                i = i + 1
            else:
                temp = molecule[i]    #if not

            if not temp in list_of_atoms:
                    list_of_atoms.append(temp)  #if atom is not in the list appends to it
    if molecule[-1] in upper:
        list_of_atoms.append(molecule[-1])  #checks last letter


    return print(list_of_atoms)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is an atom? Did you mean an element, like Au, H, He?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a regex expression that captures a capital character followed optionally by a lower character.

```
list(set(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?', 'CuBDa')))
```

But you might be overlooking numbers, i.e CO2, this will do that

```
re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*', 'C4H10FO2P')
```

If you just want to ignore the numbers, the first expression will work

Comment: OP _is_ looking for the individual element, I think. So you can just ignore the numbers.

Comment: And OP doesn't want duplicates, you can remove the duplicates using `list(set(...))` to get the final list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
import re
molecule = 'CH3COOH'
print set(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?',molecule))
```

which will print:

```
set(['H', 'C', 'O'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the Python PLY documentation and look the example of Andrew Dalke
for the parsing example with molecules.  (http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/parsing_with_ply.html)

You may define tokens with the atomic symbol and the time this atom/symbol appears in the molecule, for example for a molecule like CH3COOH (acetic acid)

```
import lex

tokens = (
   "SYMBOL",
   "COUNT"
         )

t_SYMBOL = (
     r"C[laroudsemf]?|Os?|N[eaibdpos]?|S[icernbmg]?|P[drmtboau]?|"
     r"H[eofgas]?|A[lrsgutcm]|B[eraik]?|Dy|E[urs]|F[erm]?|G[aed]|"
     r"I[nr]?|Kr?|L[iaur]|M[gnodt]|R[buhenaf]|T[icebmalh]|"
     r"U|V|W|Xe|Yb?|Z[nr]"
        )

def t_COUNT(t):
    r"\d+"
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t



lex.lex()

lex.input("CH3COOH")
for tok in iter(lex.token, None):
    print repr(tok.type), repr(tok.value)
```

When I run the code I get the following

'SYMBOL' 'C'
'SYMBOL' 'H'
'COUNT' 3
'SYMBOL' 'C'
'SYMBOL' 'O'
'SYMBOL' 'O'
'SYMBOL' 'H'

More information here
http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/